# Get file extension on external images

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to get file extension from an image in javascript, when you get it from another server which dpesn't care much about the extension...

Like on imgur, the extension isn't always true, ie. [image: .jpg], [image: .png] 
and
[image: .gif] 
are all the same image but with different extensions

Comment: you mean image format (aka mime-type)

Comment: I'll get around to answering your question just as soon as I finish watching this a few more times.

Comment: So you want to know the mime type from files on different servers with JavaScript?

Comment: @Vprimachenko Exactly! cc @ epascarello

Comment: https://github.com/rsdoiel/mimetype-js is probably what you need :).

Comment: Is it possible to use this without node?